# MS Word cannot find converter

Tags: ms-word

I have a recurring problem in MS Word (also Outlook but that is linked to Word) with an error 'Cannot find converter'. In my case it is 'MSWRD832.CNV' and 'WRD6ER32.CNV'. I don't think I am ever likely to need them but cannot manage to either uninstall or correct the error. I have swept the registry and deleted any reference to either - did not fix it. I am reading that this is linked to WordPad - which I never use. This occurs just trying to open docx files I have created myself on the exact same version of Word that throws the error.

No real big problem, can dismiss and carry on, but it happens all the time and is annoying. 
I fished out the couple of suggestions online that were not malware or irrelevant but it all amounts to 'you are trying to convert without converters' (am not) or 'clean the registry' (did it, did not help).
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try a Modify on Office installation, and ensure the filters are installed (I would suspect some of the filters under Office Shared Features | Graphics and Filters):

[image]